# Why is every conformal bijection between disks a linear fractional transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Why is every conformal bijection between disks actually a linear fractional transformation?

I thought I could justify this claim with the following idea.

Suppose $f$ is a conformal bijection from a disk $A$ to a disk $B$. Let $z_0\in A$ be arbitrary. Now there is a LFT $g$ from the unit disk to $A$ mapping 0 to $z_0$. Also, there is a LFT $h$ from the unit disk to $B$ mapping $0$ to $f(z_0)$. So altogether, $F=h^{-1}\circ f\circ g$ is a bijection on the unit disk fixing $0$, so by Schwarz' lemma, $|F(z)|\leq |z|$. Since $F^{-1}$ shares the same property, we have $\vert F^{-1}(F(z))\vert=|z|\leq |F(z)|$, so $|F(z)|=|z|$, so by Schwarz' lemma, $F(z)=cz$ for some $c$. So $F$ is a LFT, and thus $f$ is as well.

Is this valid? I was surprised to conclude $|F(z)|=|z|$ for all $z$, I wasn't expecting to find $F$ to be an isometry. Thanks all.

Comment: If you're proposing $F$ is a rotation, it shouldn't surprise you that $|F(x)|=|z|$.  I believe the proof in books is similar to what you've written.

Comment: The conformity of a linear fractional transformation is dependent on that it preserves circles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is valid. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I don't know if it that obvious, why does the conclusion that $F$ is a LFT imply also that $f $ is also a LFT?

Comment: Compositions of LFTs are LFTs.

Comment: Oh Okay, In that case can I say $f=h\circ F\circ g^{-1}$